# How to Compare AD Group with Azure AD Group and remove members if different

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

i would like to compare 2 groups and removes members from Azure AD Group if its different, but im having an error. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

```
$membersofAzureADGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Searchstring Test_Group | Get-AzureADGroupmember | Select Userprincipalname

$membersofADGroup = Get-ADGroupmember "Groupe_A" | Get-ADUser -properties Userprincipalname | Select UserPrincipalName

$RemoveUsers = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $membersofAzureADGroup -DifferenceObject $membersofADGroup -PassThru | Where SideIndicator -eq "<="

Remove-AzureADGroupMember $RemoveUsers -Members $membersofAzureADGroup
```

Remove-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot find a positional parameter that accepts the argument "@{UserPrincipalName=user@domain.com;SideIndicator=<=}"

I tried this below but still not working...

```
Remove-AzureADGroupMember $RemoveUsers -MemberID (Get-AzureADUser | where {$_.Userprincipalname -eq $MembersOfGroup1}).ObjectID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing users that are members of an Azure AD Group but are not a member of an Active Directory Group would require filtering and for that you definitely not need `Compare-Object`.

Since you're trying to find elements of an array that do not exist on another array, `Where-Object` or `.Where(..)` method should be more than enough.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$azGName = 'Test_Group'
$adGName = 'Test_Group'

$azGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Searchstring $azGName
$azMembers = Get-AzureADGroupmember $azGroup
$adMembers = (Get-ADGroupMember $adGName).Where({
    $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'
}).UserPrincipalName
# NOTE: Piping Get-ADUser to Get-ADGroupMember will get you in trouble whenever
#       there is a member that is not of the objectclass 'user'.

# Members of AZ Group that are not members of AD Group
$azMembers.Where({$_ -notin $adMembers.UserPrincipalName}).ForEach({
    "Removing $_ from $azGName"
    try
    {
        Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $azGroup.ObjectId -MemberId $_.ObjectId
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. Very appreciate for all the details!

Comment: @ak2595 happy to help, it should work as is, just update the variables `$azGName` and `$adGName`.

Comment: I also have guest users #EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com in the azGroup but they are not from my AD. Is it going to remove them?

Comment: @ak2595 it should, this script should leave both groups (Azure and AD) with the same membership having the AD Group as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have AD or Azure AD, but I followed the principles of your issue and tested the following locally on my computer. **See Below**

Why you fail is because your $RemoveUsers variable is wrong. I'd be surprised if you've not looked at what is being presented from it.

**Why It Doesn't Work**

```
$RemoveUsers = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $membersofAzureADGroup -DifferenceObject $membersofADGroup -PassThru | Where SideIndicator -eq "<="
```

**Compare Groups On A Local Computer Test**

```
## Step 1 - Place both groups into variables
$Group1 = get-localgroup -Name Administrators | Get-LocalGroupMember | Select Name
$Group2 = get-localgroup -Name Test | Get-LocalGroupMember | Select Name
## Step 2 - See All Output 
$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Group1 -DifferenceObject $Group2 -property name -passthru -IncludeEqual
## Step 3 See Only Difference in reference (source) object and select InputObject
$DifferenceInSource = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Group1 -DifferenceObject $Group2 | Where SideIndicator -eq "<=" | Select -ExpandProperty InputObject)
## Step 4 Pull Out Names
$DifferenceInSourceName = $DifferenceInSource.Name
## Split WorkGroup and Account
$SplitName = $DifferenceInSourceName.Split('\')
## Step 5 Test To See If Account Resolves
Get-LocalUser -name $SplitName[1]
```

Obviously you then structure around a **ForEach** statement to make the update on multiple references.

[image]